# Blackberry Pdf issue.... Unsupported Media Type Application/Pdf

Tags: asp.net, blackberry

This is the most annoying thing i have faced in webforms development. I have a webform which allows to download pdf file When i try to download the pdf file in blackberry browser it save the file and when i try to open it then it leads to an issue "Unsupported media type application/pdf".

Next thing I emailed the pdf file to my gmail account and its successfully converted the pdf file to a text file and opened the file. When i try to open the same pdf file in my sample application it says "Unsupported media type application/pdf".

Next thing i googled it and found that blackberry doesn't have the reader to read the pdf files. But when i view the same pdf file in Blackberry Outlook Email client it successfully opened the pdf file.

Pdf Downloading functionality is working in all the browsers on the Machine but its not working on the blackberry device.. Why Pdf files are converted to text files ? automatically...

Please help me to resolve this issue...

Comment: do you have think that this maybe an outlook email automatically functions on blackberry ?

Comment: Aristo but when i open the same pdf from my gmail account in blackberry browser its shows the pdf contents inside the text file but in my Asp.net application its  Unsupported Media Type Application/Pdf

Comment: its because gmail using the goole code that make pdf to text, but blackberry can not show it by default because did not contain this code, maybe you need to install extra program

Comment: Hey Aristos tell me 1 thing how gmail knows yes this client doesn't have pdf reader install so convert that file to text... In the blackberry app market i saw 3rd party Pdf reader applications by installing that will successfully view pdf files by downloading from the blackberry browser so is that gmail might be internally checking whether the client has reader install or not ??

Comment: The gmail is custom for your phone, so he know it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of research i found that there is no direct way to show pdf on Blackberry devuce need to purchase 3rd party software for that.

Thanks for all who helped me..